# how to add events from database to the android calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I'm adding events from database to the calendar (Etar-Calendar). I tried to load it using `insert(Events.CALENDAR_URI, values);`.

I have events for many days in the database, after loading events to the calendar it shows for 3 days and after completing loop statements events of the 3rd day will disappear and also it won't show events for further days.

```
dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);  
SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from events", null);

SimpleDateFormat startFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat endFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id"));

        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));

        date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));

        start_time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("start_time"));

        end_time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("end_time"));

        description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));

        location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("location"));

        try {
            start = date + " " + start_time;
            end = date + " " + end_time;

            eventStart = startFormat.parse(start);
            eventEnd = endFormat.parse(end);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, id);
        Log.e("MonthActivity", "eventId " + eventId);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, name);
        Log.e("MonthActivity", "eventName " + name);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, eventStart.getTime());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, eventEnd.getTime());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, String.valueOf(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta")));

        checkAppPermissions();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            return;
        }
        context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, I was passing "**id**" which is in database to `CALENDAR_ID` `values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, id);`.  We have to pass `CALENDAR_ID` as 1.